# In what library is dgesvd_?

Tags: c, lapack

I'm trying to use the function dgesvd_() in a code and just can't find the library I have to include in order to the compiler to detect it!

I've only discovered some LAPACK or something like that but couldn't see includes or relevant information anywhere.

Comment: As you mentioned, `gdesvd` is part of the LAPACK library. What is your question?

Comment: That symbol is not in any CUDA or CUSOLVER library.  See [here](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d1/d7e/group__double_g_esing_ga84fdf22a62b12ff364621e4713ce02f2.html)

Comment: My question is about how do I actually include the library into my C code so it detects it when compiling. Now it doesn't.  Jérôme (down below) is on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dgesvd` computes the singular value decomposition (SVD) of a real matrix. It is a part of LAPACK. LAPACK is not really a library but an *interface* for numerical algebra functions. The standard implementation is the one provided by [Netlib LAPACK](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/). However, the Intel MKL [also implement this](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-lapack-examples/top/least-squares-and-eigenvalue-problems/singular-value-decomposition/gesvd-function/dgesvd-example/dgesvd-example-c.html) (more efficiently than the one of Netlib). [LAPACKE](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapacke.html) is a C interface of the FORTRAN one provided by the Netlib implementation. It provides a header than can be used for C project to call LAPACK functions (linked at runtime). You could use it in your C project as long as you link a LAPACK-compatible library.

Comment: Hi Jérôme. Thank you a lot for your answer! Is really complete and you got what I was asking. My code is written in C so I think I cannot use the standard Fortran implementation. Would you recommend trying to use the Intel one (which looks more simple) or the one from Netlib, LAPACKE?

I didn't fully understand how to include / use LAPACKE in my C code, and there doesn't seem to be an explanation on their web.

I tried to use the Intel version. Copied the code on their web and tried to compile it, it didn't work. What do I need to do for it to compile? Thanks!!

Comment: I think the MKL should have this header too but I never used it. It appear to be called `mkl_lapacke.h`. Note that you may need ICC to build the example. [This](http://nicolas.limare.net/pro/notes/2014/10/31_cblas_clapack_lapacke/) may help you. Using Netlib is simpler but the performance as less great than the one of the MKL (at least on Intel hardware). If you want just to test/begin-with this, definitively use the Netlib implementation. If this is for a HPC project, then I advise you to switch to the MKL later.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jérôme! Now everything is more clear and I know what to do ^^!